# Jquery/Jquerymobile populate <select> dynamically - ERROR

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I've a database containing the options to add dynamically, after button click, in a `<select>` tag.
This is what the HTML looks like, its inside a div with `data-role="page"` (for jQuerymobile)

```
<div id="endSessionPageContent" data-role="content">
  <div data-role='fieldcontain' id="endSessionForm">
  </div>
</div>
```

Basically, I get some values from a sqlite database, and then I'd like to put them inside the "endSessionForm" div. The data should be displayed both with `<inputs>` and `<select>` elements.
The function looks like this (no sql interaction here, for simplicity):

```
function buildPage(divId){
  $("#endSessionForm").empty();
  var div = "<div><label>aaa</label><input></input></div>";
  div += "<div><label>bbb</label><input></input></div>";
  div += "<div><select><option>1</option><option>2</option><option>3</option></select></div>";
  $('#endSessionForm').append(div);
  $("#endSessionForm").trigger('create');
}
```

Then after some event, I call the buildPage function (see this jsfiddle for a live example http://jsfiddle.net/xdR43/12/). The trigger(`create`) is used to force the UI reload:

As you can see, the `<select>` is not properly created. The jsfiddle page throws this error:

```
Syntax error, unrecognized expression: :nth-child
```

while, the same code in my app throws this error:

```
'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'this.list[0].appendChild')
```

What do you think is wrong? Thanks for any help, I hope I gave you all the informations you need. If you need more, ask and I'll add em.

Thanks again, best regards

__*_*___*EDIT****_*__*_*____**

this is the entire function:

```
function buildPage(divId){
  $(divId).empty();
  for(var i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++){
  var area = results.rows.item(i).area;
  var campo = results.rows.item(i).campo;
  var campoWOspcs = campo.replace(/ /g,"_");
  var valori = results.rows.item(i).valori;
  var div = "<div><label for='newCompany_"+campoWOspcs+"'>"+campo+":</label>";
if(valori == ""){   //input
  div += "<input type='text' name='"+campoWOspcs+"' id='newCompany_"+campoWOspcs+"' placeholder='"+campo+"'></input>";
}else{  //select        
  div += "<select name='"+campoWOspcs+"' multiple='multiple' id='newCompany_"+campoWOspcs+"'><option>Select "+campo+"</option>";
  var split = valori.split(";");
  for(var j = 0; j < (split.length -1); j++ ){
        div += "<option>"+split[j]+"</option>";
  }
  div += "</select>";
    }
    div += "</div>";
$(divId).append(div);//alert(div);
  }
  $(divId).append(div);
  $(divId).trigger('create');   
}
```

Comment: You should give us the code that throws the error.

Comment: I forgot to say: in my app, I have 1++ <select> tags to be appended to the div. Only the first <select> gives me problem, the others work fine, and are correctly filled with <option> data.

Comment: Oddly enough if I delete *all your JavaScript* the `:nth-child` error remains. Suggests a problem on JS Fiddle's part, maybe?

Comment: added the entire function. the error is thrown by jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js:161 :\

Comment: The "Syntax" Error is thrown in a jQueryMobile function - I have no idea why. Your code seems to be fine. You should use the latest (stable) version unminified and trace down the error with a debugger.

Comment: Nothing new :( i found that the error is on line 7020 of jquery.mobile-1.1.0.js (TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'self.list[0].appendChild'). I tryed to print self.list.length, and it's 0 O_O any idea?

Comment: MAYBE SOLVED: replaced $(divId).empty(); with $(divId).html(''), and removed $(divId).trigger('create'); . Now it seems to work. Thanks